# Why was my comment and the reply deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Why was my comment on [Explain down votes](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2914/23541) deleted? Why was the reply to it also deleted? And no others?

Answer (score 7):

It was flagged as inappropriate by the community and the flag was deemed helpful since the comment didn't actually add anything constructive to the discussion. It was an out-of-context claim with no backing and was discouraging to a new user of the community. To put it more bluntly, it looked like a passerby using someone else's unrelated problem to go on a sidetracking rant:

> Could be worse some one could be going through all your posts and down voting or un-upvoting them every day. Like someone here does. Ignore it.

And with the comment gone, the reply to it was superfluous.

Comment: Telling op to ignore the downvotes is not constructive? Right.

Comment: The comment was a little longer, but I'm sure you know.

Comment: Out of context righhhht.

Comment: Backing. So I should like them to the meta questions with screenshots proving it? Okay, understood.

Comment: @cde Still not the appropriate place to do that anyway.